# Swing (Java) Category List

Tags: java, swing

everyone.

I'm currently working on a project which is written in Java. As one of my features I want the application to display List of workout plans that are saved in the databases. Furthermore, I want the user to be able to click on particular instance of the workout Plan so that new JFrame is opened with further details which will be populated from the database.
You can see what I mean in the picture below, this is how I want my list to look like.

[image: Diet Plans]

For this application I'm using Swing components to model my GUI. Its very important for me that those items within a list will act as a button so that you can open up new JFrame, but at the same time the content must be populated from database. Also when a new Workout Plan is added to the database the list must be updated and the item that will be added to that list has to be of the same format.

My question is whether it's possible to design that kind of list using Swing components, and if it is how would you do it.

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I did mean to say Swing(Java), my apologies if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with swing but, I think you can set your panel into a grid layout. Then divide the grid layout so that there are, for example, 10 rows and 1 column. Afterwards, fill the grid layout with JButton's. Whenever a button is pressed, it will open up a JFrame.

I feel like there's a better way to do this though.